# Remove whitespace on bottom of footer in Firefox (bootstrap)

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, firefox, margin, footer, padding

I have a white bar on the bottom of my footer in firefox only. Screenshot: https://www.dropbox.com/s/6bjt0y451lxxs94/Screenshot%202014-10-07%2011.38.13.png?dl=0 I tried everything I could think of to remove it, please help! Even if I remove every inside the footer it still has the whitespace below so I don't know what's causing it.

I have pasted basically my entire code and I am using bootstrap 3, thank you!

HTML:

```
 <div class="navbar"> <!----top navbar--->
    <div class="container constrain-960">

<a class="brand" href="/" target="_top">
  <img src="" height="26">
</a>

    <div class="pull-right">
      <ul class="navnav navbar-nav">
    <li class="hidden-xs learn-more"><a href="">Learn More</a></li>
        <li class="top-cta btn-warning"><a href="">Raise Money Now</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
 </div> <!----/top navbar--->


     <div class="row"> <!----main title--->
      <div class="text-center title">
        <h1>this is a title</h1>
    <h1 class="sub-title"><p class="subtitle fancy"><span>and a subtitle</span></p></h1>  
      </div>
    </div> <!----/main title--->


<div class="table-background"> <!----begin table section--->
  <div class="container constrain-960">

<div class="table-responsive">
<table class="table">
  <thead style="background-color: #e5e5e5">
    <tr style="height: 20px;">
      <th>website</th>
      <th class="fee">Fee</th>
      <th>Ways&nbsp;to&nbsp;Contribute</th>
      <th>Ways&nbsp;to&nbsp;Share</th>
  <th>Important&nbsp;Info</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td><img src="" width="165" height="40" alt=""></td>
      <td class="fee">5%</td>
      <td class="contribute">PayPal, WePay</td>
      <td style="min-width: 155px;"></td>
  <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td class="fee">9%</td>
      <td class="contribute">PayPal</td>
      <td></td>
  <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td class="fee">5%</td>
      <td class="contribute">PayPal</td>
      <td></td>
  <td></td>
    </tr>
 <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td class="fee">5%</td>
      <td class="contribute">PayPal</td>
      <td></td>
  <td></td>
    </tr>
  <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td class="fee">5%</td>
      <td class="contribute">PayPal</td>
      <td></td>
  <td></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
</div>
  </div>
</div> <!----end table section--->

<div class="container constrain-960">
     <div class="row" style="margin-top: 40px;"> 
    <div class="text-center">
    <h2 class="benefits-title">Benefits</h2>
    </div>
    </div>
<div class="benefits">
   <div class="row" style="margin-top: 30px;">
      <div class="col-md-6">
     <img src="/crowdfundingca/assets/images/check.png" alt="check mark" width="40" style="float:left"><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. </p>
      </div>  
    <div class="col-md-6">  
     <img src="/crowdfundingca/assets/images/check.png" alt="check mark" width="40" style="float:left"><p>CLorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. </p>
         </div>
   </div>
   <div class="row middle-row">
      <div class="col-md-6">  
        <img src="/crowdfundingca/assets/images/check.png" alt="check mark" width="40" style="float:left"><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. </p>
       </div>
     <div class="col-md-6">   
        <img src="/crowdfundingca/assets/images/check.png" alt="check mark" width="40" style="float:left"><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
      </div>
      </div>
    <div class="row" style="margin-bottom: 20px;">
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <img src="/crowdfundingca/assets/images/check.png" alt="check mark" width="40" style="float:left"><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. </p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <img src="/crowdfundingca/assets/images/check.png" alt="check mark" width="40" style="float:left"><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. </p>
      </div>
    </div>
    </div>
      <div class="row">

    </div>
    </div> 

    <div class="carousel-background"> <!----carousel section--->
   <!-- <div class="text-center">
    <h2 style="margin-bottom: -40px; padding-top: 15px;">Examples</h2>
    </div> -->

  <div class="container constrain-960">
    <div id="carousel-example-generic" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
  <!-- Indicators -->
  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
  <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
  <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="1"></li>
  <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="2"></li>
  </ol>

 <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
<img src="/crowdfundingca/assets/images/widgets.png" class="widgets" width="80" alt="widget     example">
<div class="carousel-inner">
<div class="item active">

</div>
<div class="item">

</div>
   <div class="item">

</div>
</div>

<!-- Controls -->
<a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="prev">
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
</a>
<a class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="next">
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
</a>
</div>
  </div>
</div>

    </body>
  <div id="fr-footer-container">
    <div class="container constrain-960"> 
        <footer>
            <div id="fr-footer">
                    <div class="footer-content row" id="footer-main">
                        <div class="col-md-3">
                            <div class="learn-more-box">
                                <h5>Learn more</h5>
                                <ul class="learn-more">
                                    <li><a target="_blank" href="">Blog</a></li>
                                    <li><a target="_blank" href="">Support</a></li>
                                    <li><a target="_top" href="/pages/faq">FAQ</a></li>
                                    <li><a target="_top" href="/pages/about">About</a></li>
                                    <li><a target="_top" href="/pages/press">Press</a></li>
                                    <li><a target="_top" href="/pages/contact">Contact</a></li>
                                    <li><a target="_top" href="/pages/service-fees">Fees</a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-3">
                            <h5>Crowdfund anything</h5>
                            <ul class="learn-more">
                                <li><a target="_top" href="/pages/raise-money-for-healthcare">Healthcare &amp; Medical Bills</a></li>
                                <li><a target="_top" href="/pages/raise-money-for-accidents">Accidents &amp; Disasters</a></li>
                                <li><a target="_top" href="/pages/raise-money-for-memorials">Funerals &amp; Memorials</a></li>
                                <li><a target="_top" href="/pages/raise-money-for-animals">Animals &amp; Pets</a>  </li>
                                <li><a target="_top" href="/pages/raise-money-for-non-profits">Non-profits</a></li>
                                <li><a title="Raise money now" onclick="_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'signup', 'create', 'footer']);" target="_top" href="/create" class="highlight" id="get-started-footer">Raise money now</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-3">
                            <h5>Business solutions</h5>
                            <ul class="learn-more">
                                <li><a target="_blank" href="/pages/business/crowdfunding-for-business">Small business &amp; Entrepreneurs</a></li>
                                <li><a target="_top" href="">Crowd power your enterprise</a></li>

                                <li><a target="_top" href="/pages/partner-with-us">Become an affiliate</a></li>
                                <li><a target="_top" href="">Business blog</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-3">


                            <h5>Follow us</h5>
                            <div>
            <a href="" target="_blank" title="Facebook" class="connect-icon facebook"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a>
                <a href="" target="_blank" title="Twitter" class="connect-icon twitter"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a>
            <a href="" target="_blank" title="Google+" class="connect-icon google-plus"><i class="fa fa-google-plus"></i></a>
            <a href="" target="_blank" title="Blog" class="connect-icon comment"><i class="fa fa-comments"></i></a>

            <a href="" target="_blank" title="LinkedIn" class="connect-icon linkedin"><i class="fa fa-linkedin"></i></a>
            <a href="" target="_blank" title="YouTube channel" class="connect-icon youtube"><i class="fa fa-youtube"></i></a>

                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>


                <div class="footer-content row" id="footer-links">
                    <div class="col-md-12 small muted">

                        <p class="small muted secondary">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>    


                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

        </footer>
    </div>
  </div>

</html>
```

CSS:

```
body {
min-width: 320px;
overflow-x: hidden;
background: url(/crowdfundingca/assets/images/page-bg_1x1000.png) repeat-x top left;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}

html {
overflow-x: hidden;
background-color: #FEFEFE;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}

.constrain-960{
max-width: 960px !important;
}

h2 {
font-family: "Palatino Linotype","Book Antiqua",Georgia,Paltino,Times,"Times New Roman",serif;
color: #44474d;
font-size: 26px;
font-weight: normal;
letter-spacing: normal;
margin-top: 0px;
}

/*----------------------------------------Top nav bar---------------------------------------*/
.navbar {
background-color: #FFF;
height: 46px !important;
box-shadow: 1px 1px 5px rgb(153, 153, 153);
position: fixed;
width: 100%;
z-index: 99;
border-radius: 0;
}

 .navbar .brand {
float: left;
display: block;
margin: 10px 15px 0 0;
font-size: 0;
line-height: 1000;
font-weight: 200;
color: #222;
}

.navbar .learn-more a{
color: #222;
padding-top: 13px;
padding-bottom: 16px;
}

.navbar .learn-more a:hover{
color: #222;
background: #F7F7F9;
}

.navbar .top-cta a{
color: white;
font-weight: bold;
}

.navnav {
list-style: none outside none;
margin-bottom: 0;
padding-left: 0;
}
.navnav > li {
display: block;
position: relative;
}

.navnav > li > a {
display: block;
padding: 6px 10px;
position: relative;
}
.navnav > li > a:hover, .nav > li > a:focus {
text-decoration: none;
}

/*----------------------------------------Table---------------------------------------*/

.city {
margin-right: 20px;
margin-top: -125px;
z-index: -5;
}

td.fee {
font-weight: bold;
font-size: 18px;
padding: 0 25px 0 25px !important;
}

th.fee {
padding: 0 25px 7px 25px !important;
}

td.contribute {
font-size: 16px;
}


.table-background {
padding-top: 20px;
background-color: #e5e5e5;
height: 510px;
width: 100%;
border-radius: 0px;
} 

table {
border-collapse: separate;
border-radius: 10px;
}

td {
background: #fff;
vertical-align:middle !important;
}

tr {
height: 80px;
}


.table > thead > tr > th, .table > tbody > tr > th, .table > tfoot > tr > th, .table > thead > tr >      td, .table > tbody > tr > td, .table > tfoot > tr > td {
border-top: 2px solid #e5e5e5;
line-height: 1.42857;
padding: 8px;

}
.table > thead > tr > th {
border-bottom: 2px solid #e5e5e5;

}

/*----------------------------------------Carousel--------------------------------------*/

.carousel-background {
background-color: #e5e5e5;
height: 350px;
width: 100%;
border-radius: 0px;
}
.carousel {
margin-top: 50px;
height: 250px;
background-color: white;
border-radius: 10px !important;
padding: 0 50px 0 55px;
}

.item {
margin-top: 25px;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
width: 820px;
}

.widgets {
margin-top: -30px !important;
margin-left: -80px;
position: absolute;
z-index: 99;
}

/*----------------------------------------Footer--------------------------------------*/
#fr-footer-container {
background-color: #44474d;
border-top: 1px solid rgb(221, 221, 221);
color: rgb(136, 136, 136);
font-size: 12px;
bottom: 0;
width:100%;
}


#fr-footer {
color: rgb(136, 136, 136);
margin: 0;
overflow: hidden;
padding-top: 20px;
width: 100%;
}

#fr-footer a{
color: #e5e5e5;
}

#fr-footer h5{
color: rgb(153, 153, 153);
}

#fr-footer .footer-content {
margin-bottom: 12px;
padding-bottom: 12px;
text-align: left;
}

#fr-footer div {
overflow: hidden !important; 
}

ul.dot-between {
display: inline;
list-style: none outside none;
margin: 0;
}

.small {
font-size: 10pt;
}
.muted {
color: rgb(153, 153, 153);
}

#fr-footer ul.learn-more {
list-style: none outside none;
margin: 0;
}

#footer-main {
font-size: 14px;
}

ul, ol {
margin: 0 0 10px 25px;
padding: 0;
}
```

Comment: Fixed it myself, adding position absolute to footer basically did it.

Comment: Please do not use "bootstrap" tag, use "twitter-bootstrap" since it means something else.

Comment: Please answer your own question, as leaving it will jam the system. :)